# How to make a Discord Bot respond when two conditions are both met?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm working on a basic discord bot using discord.py and repl.it, and am trying to get a basic response system going. Basically, I'm trying to make it look at words from two lists and only reply if it gets words from both lists. Right now my code looks like this:

```
    if any(word in msg for word in mean and bidoof):
      await message.channel.send(random.choice(bidoof_angry))
```

I tried to use the "and" operator to take words from "mean" and "bidoof" but it's acting almost like I feel "or" should. It replies when it sees a word from the "bidoof" list, even if there are no words form the other list in the message. I'm very new to this, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple! Just use the AND operator.

```
 if any(word in msg for word in mean) and bidoof:
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(bidoof_angry))
```

The upper code should work if you mean to check if bidoof is True.

Comment: You don't need the `is True`, you can just write it as `and bidoof:`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice it!

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to edit your answer :)